# How to update a frequency table based on a third variable?

Tags: r, frequency

I have a data frame that summaries the different class sequences of three years (2006,2007,2008), the variable count indicating the number of occurrence of a class sequence:

```
df<-data.frame(count=c(150,33,35,26,15,65), 
           Y.2006=c("a","a","a","d","d","d"), 
           Y.2007=c("a","b","b","c","c","c"),
           Y.2008=c("a","b","a","c","c","d") )
```

that looks like:

```
  count Y.2006 Y.2007 Y.2008 
1   150      a      a      a     
2    33      a      b      b        
3    35      a      b      a        
4    26      d      c      c        
5    15      d      c      c         
6    65      d      c      d
```

I compute the sequence of 2006-2007:

```
df$Y.2006_2007<-paste(df$Y.2006, df$Y.2007)
```

The result:

```
  count Y.2006 Y.2007 Y.2008 Y.2006_2007
1   150      a      a      a         a a
2    33      a      b      b         a b
3    35      a      b      a         a b
4    26      d      c      c         d c
5    15      d      c      c         d c
6    65      d      c      d         d c
```

I would like the number of occurrence of Y.2006_2007 for the different class of 2008.
So I do:

```
table(df$Y.2006_2007, df$Y.2008)
```

Resulting in :

```
      a b c d
  a a 1 0 0 0
  a b 1 1 0 0
  d c 0 0 2 1
```

Now, I would like to update these results based on the count variable of the initial data frame (df) to take into account the number of occurrence of the class sequences. So I would like:

```
      a   b   c   d
a a 150   0   0   0
a b  35  33   0   0
d c   0   0  41  65
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xtabs` to do that with base R:

```
xtabs(formula = count ~ Y.2006_2007 + Y.2008, data = df)

              Y.2008
  Y.2006_2007   a   b   c   d
          a a 150   0   0   0
          a b  35  33   0   0
          d c   0   0  41  65
```

And in case you need a data.frame, you can just wrap it in `as.data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(xtabs(formula = count ~ Y.2006_2007 + Y.2008, data = df))
   Y.2006_2007 Y.2008 Freq
1          a a      a  150
2          a b      a   35
3          d c      a    0
4          a a      b    0
5          a b      b   33
6          d c      b    0
7          a a      c    0
8          a b      c    0
9          d c      c   41
10         a a      d    0
11         a b      d    0
12         d c      d   65
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Y.2006_2007 ~ Y.2008, sum, value.var = "count")

##   Y.2006_2007   a  b  c  d
## 1         a a 150  0  0  0
## 2         a b  35 33  0  0
## 3         d c   0  0 41 65
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
unite(Y.2006_2007, Y.2006, Y.2007) %>% #created column Y.2006-2007 
group_by(Y.2006_2007, Y.2008) %>%
summarize(count=sum(count)) %>%
spread(Y.2008, count, fill=0)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

#   Y.2006_2007   a  b  c  d
# 1         a_a 150  0  0  0
# 2         a_b  35 33  0  0
# 3         d_c   0  0 41 65
```